# Set DEFAULT value to row position in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, row-number

I want to alter an existing table by adding a column and setting the default value of all existing row to its position, basically emulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function but for the `DEFAULT` statement.

Here is an example table with what I want in the `order` column:

```
id|name  |order|
--+------+-----+
 1|foo   |    1|
 8|bar   |    2|
 9|toto  |    3|
```

I've tried doing :

```sql
SET @row_number = 1;
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table
    ADD COLUMN order int(11) DEFAULT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1);
```

and :

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_table ADD COLUMN `order` int(11) DEFAULT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

but without success. Is what I want possible in a .sql script ?

Comment: Just use an `auto_increment` column.

Comment: If you want exact `ROW_NUMBER()` and window functions in the `SELECT` queries. Having an INSERT/DELETE alter all the rows in a table isn't something SQL is designed to do.